# Shap for LSTM - features as timesteps

Tags: lstm, shap

I am seeking guidance as to how I can use Shap for interpretability  when I feed my features (29 of them) as time steps using LSTM.

So my training dataset has shape `(samples,29,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

To get an explanation you can just treat each of the time steps as a separate feature.

However you should be aware that SHAP masks/hides features to determine their importance. How you mask features matters, and it is more tricky for time series data to mask features while not introducing artifacts into the input data. So a better approach would be to account for this and build your own `shap.maskers.Masker` subclass that masks the data in a realistic way (like filling in masked values with their neighboring values). Adding a time series masker to the library could also be posted as a feature request / PR.